# Microsoft Graph SDK for SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am searching for ways to use the Microsoft Graph SDK for uploading a file to SharePoint. Currently I cannot find any example.

Has anyone tried to use the SDK for uploading file to SharePoint before? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found it. Yay! Praise God!

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/208

Answer (score 1):

In general, the structure of the SDK calling pattern mirrors the REST API. The path is built up by objects representing resources in the Graph API, then the request is composed (by explicitly invoking 'request'), and the verb is specified ("getAsync", "addAsync", "updateAsync").

For instance, something like `GET ~/sites/<site id>/drives` would look like `graphClient.Sites[<site id>].Drives.Request().GetAsync();`

For creating resources, you first instantiate the resource and set any properties.

```
ListItem myListItem = new ListItem();
```

Then you build the request and specify the verb to be `addAsync`

`ListItem responseItem = await graphClient.Sites[<site id>].Lists[<list id>].Items.Request().addAsync(myListItem);`